# Algorithmic ideas to multiply two tall & skinny matrices into one large square matrix?

Tags: algorithms, approximation, randomized-algorithms, matrices, linear-algebra

This problems comes from AI, and it looks something like this:

I am supposed to multiply two floating-point matrices `A * B`. `A` typically has the size of `(1k to 10k) times 32`, while `B` is of the size `32 times (1k to 10k)`. The result would be a large square matrix of size `(1k to 10k) times (1k to 10k)`.

I need to do this in very large batches (lots of `A`s and `B`s), so I need to improve throughput.

A and B are both dynamically generated, so no pre-calculation is possible. However, since it's an AI problem, approximation can be a good idea, because AIs can cope with errors.

I usually work in the field of computer architecture, so I don't really need tips on parallel computing, memory, etc.

What I am looking for are **interesting mathematical/algorithmic views** on this. Like all sorts of weird algebraic tricks that might help me approximate this.

**Any new perspective would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: `large batches (lots of As and Bs)` all pairs products, or $A_iB_i$? `Any new perspective would be greatly appreciated` It would help to know what you consider well known/established. `interesting mathematical/algorithmic views` At fist glance, recent work would seem to centre on mechanics. (The Intel® Math Kernel Library seems to have given the subject some attention.) Sketching the context might help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-linear-algebra